# Derivation of component in Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If 
$$(1): \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dX}  \frac{dX}{dx} = y'\frac{dX}{dx}$$

and

$$(2): \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = y''(\frac{dX}{dx})^2 + y'\frac{d^2X}{dx^2}   $$

were true, I am wondering how $$(3): y''(\frac{dX}{dx})^2$$ was derived.

My initial attempt was to show that both components in the sum of (2) needed to be able to change into the form 
$$(2*): \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

I am unsure if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  use the product rule:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{dy}{dX}\dfrac{dX}{dx} \right]=\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{dy}{dX}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dx} +\dfrac{dy}{dX}\left( \dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{dX}{dx} \right)
$$
 now the chain rule for the first term:
$$
\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{dy}{dX}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dx}=\left(\dfrac{d}{dX}\dfrac{dy}{dX}\dfrac{dX}{dx} \right)\dfrac{dX}{dx}=
\left(\dfrac{d^2y}{dX^2}\dfrac{dX}{dx}\right)\dfrac{dX}{dx}=
\dfrac{d^2y}{dX^2}\left(\dfrac{dX}{dx}\right)^2
$$
and you find the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply both the chain rule and product rule to $(1)$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}(y'(X(x))) &= \frac{d}{dx} \left( y'(X(x)) \frac{dX(x)}{dx} \right) \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} (y') \frac{dX(x)}{dx} + y' \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dX}{dx} \right)
\end{align*}

Do you have it from here?

Comment: How does $\frac{d}{dx} (y') \frac{dX(x)}{dx}$ equate to $y'' (\frac{dX(x)}{dx})^2$? Where do we find the extra $\frac{dX(x)}{dx}$ ?

Comment: Use the chain rule just like you did for (1)! $\frac{d}{dx}(y') = \frac{d}{dx}(y'(X(x))) = y''(X(x)) X'(x) = y'' \frac{dX}{dx}$, so $\frac{d}{dx} (y') \frac{dX(x)}{dx} = y'' \frac{dX}{dx} \cdot \frac{dX}{dx} = \ldots$